# Removing backslash from strings in R

Tags: regex, r, replace, backslash

I want to remove `list(\"` and `\")`from strings such as `list(\"TSPAN6\")` and get `TSPAN6`. I tried to do that with `grep` function, however I have problem with backslashes included the strings.
I tried:

```
gsub('list(\\"','', "list(\"TSPAN6\")", fixed=T)
```

but it does not work?!
I appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using one single `gsub`.

```
x <- c("list(\"TSPAN6\")")
x
[1] "list(\"TSPAN6\")"
gsub('list|[[:punct:]]', "", x)
[1] "TSPAN6"
```

Answer (score 3):

I found it:

```
a <- gsub('list(\"','', "list(\"TSPAN6\")", fixed=T)
gsub('\")','', a, fixed=T)
[1] "TSPAN6"
```