# Remove backslash from string

Tags: r, regex, string

I am unable to remove backslash using R. 
Input:

```
text="tweets\302"
```

Tried solution:

```
gsub('[[:punct:]]',"",text)
```

Expected result:

```
tweets302
```

Actual Result: `"tweets\302"`

I tried following this answer:

[Removing backslash from strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728090/removing-backslash-from-strings-in-r)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `gsub(..., fixed = TRUE)` so that it's interpreted as a string literal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace single backslash in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/how-to-replace-single-backslash-in-r)

Comment: @AkhilNair doesn't work. > gsub("[[:punct:]]","",text,fixed = TRUE)
[1] "tweets\302"

Comment: Are you actually entering `text="tweets\302"` (which is equivalent to `text <- "tweets\302"`)? If so, the problem is that the backslash in that definition is interpreted as the escape character. You probably meant to enter `text="tweets\\302"` instead. And you should not use `fixed=TRUE` in the `gsub` call.

Comment: I am reading from a file where it has that way.

Comment: Do you mean you are reading the file with your eyes, or the computer is reading the file using some command like `source` or `readLines`? In any case, after reading from the file, what is displayed when you enter `text` and press Enter? If it is `[1] "tweets\\302"` then the string contains a non-escape backslash and your `gsub` call should work. If it is `[1] "tweets` followed by some strange symbol, then the backslash was interpreted as the escape character and the string does not contain a backslash.

Comment: > text
[1] "tweets\302"

Comment: How exactly was `text` created? For example, did you use `source` to run a script in which one line was `text="tweets\302"`? Also, what do you get when you enter `nchar(text)`?

Comment: I had used readLines to read a file with tweets. and then tried to clean it.  >nchar(text)
[1] 7

Comment: How **exactly** was text created? You need to give **full detail** so that another person can reproduce what you did. Then the explanation will probably become clear. nchar being 7 shows that \302 is a single character, not four characters.

Comment: I pulled data from twitter using twitter4j api using java and wrote it to a file. from it I read it into R using readLines. yes it seems that \302 is a character.

Comment: Did the file contain just `tweets\302`, or did it contain `text="tweets\302"`?

Comment: Just tweets\302

Comment: OK. I made a text-file called myFile.txt that just contained `tweets\302`, and then did `x <- readLines("myFile.txt"); nchar(x)`, and the result was 10. (This happened whether the encoding was ANSI or UTF-8.) What do you get when you do exactly this?